# Why I can't add two fields to the map pin on iOS - xamarin

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin

I have e `CustomMapRenderer` on iOS project and I want to add two more fields in the marker click.

In the `CustomMKAnnotationView.cs` I create a two more objects - `CodeNum` and `AlertLevel`:

```
    using MapKit;

namespace MaritsaTundzhaForecast.iOS
{
    public class CustomMKAnnotationView : MKAnnotationView
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public string Url { get; set; }

        public int AlertLevel { get; set; }

        public int CodeNum { get; set; }

        public CustomMKAnnotationView(IMKAnnotation annotation, string id)
            : base(annotation, id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

In `CustomMapRenderer.cs` I use this line of code to show it but when I click on the pin they do not appear:

```
((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).AlertLevel = customPin.AlertLevel;
((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).CodeNum = customPin.CodeNum;
```

This is the full code of `GetViewForAnnotation`:

```
 protected override MKAnnotationView GetViewForAnnotation(MKMapView mapView, IMKAnnotation annotation)
    {
        MKAnnotationView annotationView = null;

        if (annotation is MKUserLocation)
            return null;

        var customPin = GetCustomPin(annotation as MKPointAnnotation);
        if (customPin == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Custom pin not found");
        }

        annotationView = mapView.DequeueReusableAnnotation(customPin.Name);
        if (annotationView == null)
        {
            annotationView = new CustomMKAnnotationView(annotation, customPin.Name);
            annotationView.Image = UIImage.FromFile("pin.png");
            annotationView.CalloutOffset = new CGPoint(0, 0);
            annotationView.LeftCalloutAccessoryView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile("green.png"));
            
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Name = customPin.Name;
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).Url = customPin.Url;
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).AlertLevel = customPin.AlertLevel;
            ((CustomMKAnnotationView)annotationView).CodeNum = customPin.CodeNum;
        }
        annotationView.CanShowCallout = true;

        return annotationView;
    }
```

I have `OnDidSelectAnnotation` methods, but I don't know what to write inside to display `CodeNum` and `AlertLevel`:

```
void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
        customPinView = new UIView();

        if (customView.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
        {
            customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
            /*
            var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
            image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("green.png");
            customPinView.AddSubview(image);
            */
            customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
            e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);
        }
    }

    void OnDidDeselectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!e.View.Selected)
        {
            customPinView.RemoveFromSuperview();
            customPinView.Dispose();
            customPinView = null;
        }
    }
```

I use this code to create a new label but I want to put this values from `customView.AlertLevel.ToString();` inside in the info window.

```
void OnDidSelectAnnotationView(object sender, MKAnnotationViewEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomMKAnnotationView customView = e.View as CustomMKAnnotationView;
        customPinView = new UIView();

        if (customView.Name.Equals("Xamarin"))
        {
            customPinView.Frame = new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84);
            /*
            var image = new UIImageView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
            image.Image = UIImage.FromFile("green.png");
            customPinView.AddSubview(image);
            */

            customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 75));
            e.View.AddSubview(customPinView);

           
            var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 84));
            label.Text = customView.AlertLevel.ToString();
            customPinView.AddSubview(label);
        }
    }
```

This is screenshot how look now:
[image: screen]

Comment: Can you give me example ?

Comment: if you want the info window to change, modify CustomMKAnnotationView to fit your needs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to modify the UI to display the additional data

```
// you will need to experiment with the Bounds to fit your UI
var label = new UILabel(new CGRect(0, 0, 100, 50));
label.Text = customView.AlertLevel;
customPinView.AddSubview(label);
```

Comment: I try with your code but I still cannot see the label when I click on some marker, Can you check I will update my question..

Comment: I change new CGRect(90, 100, 200, 84) to this values, but I need to put this value in the info window.. I try with customPinView.Center = new CGPoint(0, -(e.View.Frame.Height + 150));  (change 75 to 150) but not work for me ..I will attach a screenshot

Comment: that screenshot clearly shows the green check icon that you have commented out so it appears that your changes are not even running

Comment: I had in mind the text below info window -> how to put it in self into info window ?

Comment: Код на тревога (1-4): 1 I wanted to show that on the screenshot I want to set this text in the info window itself.

Comment: why did you accept the answer if it doesn't work?

Comment: it works, but my next question was how to arrange it in the info window, after which my question was closed? why  ?

Comment: see my comment above - it is the same process, you need to modify CustomMKAnnotationView to fit your needs

Comment: I have CustomMKAnnotationView on 100 lines which of all exactly ?